# Error while creating and Saving Page under TeamSite

Tags: 2010, web-part, sitepages

Under SP 2010 TeamSite, When i create Page by going `Site Settings -> Create Page`, the page created but after writing something on the page when i click on save button, I get following as shown in image below `(You must specify a value for this required field)`: After clicking on OK button on error page, it saves. But i see same error again when i add any web part on the page. I have added Shared documents web part which have many folders and documents. whenever i add new document or click on any existing folder on shared documents web part on that page, i see same error every time as below: I am totally stuck and could not figure out whats wrong, Need help?

[image]

Comment: did you customized your master page or page layouts?

Comment: There is probably a required field on the content type of this page in the library it is created in that isn't present on your page layout.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, yes we have set custom master page couple of years before for our customer. But we are getting this error now

Comment: this is sahrepoint, try this one http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/09/you-must-specify-value-for-this.html

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: I have tried what is written in this blog. But i am still getting this error? Any idea to fix this? I am just using SharedDocuments Web part on the page. Which content type this library use?